# Swap function for array of structs

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have final project w/ array of structs

```
typedef struct
{
int id;
char first_name[25];
char last_name[25];
char address[35];
char city[25];
char state[3];
char zip[6];
char phone[11];
char birth[9];
char ssn[10];
char gender[1];
} dataWD_t;
```

There are 112 arrays.
I want to know how to build the swap function.
I've written many non struct swaps, so even just a prototype with short explanation would be nice.

This is what I have so far
Prototype:
    void carbon_swap(dataWD_t *, dataWD_t * );

```
void carbon_swap(dataWD_t *dataWD, dataWD_t *dataWD1){
   dataWD_t *temp = (dataWD_t*) calloc(sizeof(dataWD),sizeof(dataWD));
    *temp = *dataWD;
    *dataWD = *dataWD1;
    *dataWD1 = *temp;
    memset(temp, 0, sizeof(dataWD));
}
```

For example, swap 
    strcpy(dataWD[2].first_name,dataWD[3].last_name);
I need this to work for my sort functions.

Comment: 1. You should explain what's wrong with that code. 2. Don't cast the return of `malloc` and family. 3. `calloc(sizeof(dataWD),sizeof(dataWD));` is quite likely not what you want to do

Comment: Furthermore, if you `calloc` something, make sure to `free` it after using it

Comment: Use a local variable of type `dataWD_t` (not a pointer).  Do not use `calloc()`; do not use `memset()`; if you must use `calloc()`, you must also use `free()` to avoid a memory leak.  Also note that you would not need to use `strcpy()` that I can see.